# Python: class method return name

Tags: python, class, object, methods

This should be quite basic. I have a class and one of the traits is name. 
Withtin the program I have two such classes - for 1 the name works e.g. someclass.name shows a name for the other someotherclass.name doesn't. I've been looking at types and trying to figure out what got derailed with no success.

```
class someotherthing(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, revisions = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.revisions = 0

examplething = someotherthing()
examplething.name = str(myname).strip() #added strip() while brainstorming

listofthings.append(examplething)


for thing in listofthings:
     print thing.name
```

and the results I achieve are:

```
thing.name:  <built-in method strip of str object at 0x1318930>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to **call** `.strip()` and stored the method instead:

```
>>> ' something '.strip
<built-in method strip of str object at 0x102719d80>
>>> ' something '.strip()
'something'
```

Note the first version, I only reference the method without calling it, resulting in a reference to the function. The second line shows that if you call `.strip()` the stripped text is returned.

Comment: 5 minutes until I can accept. That was the problem - '.strip' vs. '.strip()' - which developed trying to resolve a problem where through a series of linkages an object was being stored instead of a string.

Comment: Was the question edited without showing in the history? At the moment, the code *is* showing with the `()`. (voted to close as Too Localized anyway)

Comment: @Wooble: It wasn't. It was the output that gave me the clue.